# In ActiveMQ whether MessageListener depends on data log files of message store

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ as a JMS implementation server in my application. Scenario is like, there is a topic over which I have many durable subscribers which consumes the published message and a message listener which save the data from message object to central DB server. There is a producer thread which keeps on publishing persistent message over the same topic. I am using KahaDB for persistent Message Store. As soon as a message is published, kahaDB creates a data log file in message store to persist message until all durable subscriber consume it. I want to know if at any point, I shutdown the JMS server and delete all the data log files, what would be the impact. Will it be just that few durable subscriers will not receive a message which was there in data log files for them to be consumed or is there a possibility that few message didn't got saved in central database which is done by message listener over this topic.
Any hint or help is greatly appreciated......
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you stop and start your broker, regardless of whether you delete your data files or not, topic consumer that have not already received a published message will no longer receive it. The reason behind this is that messages sent to a topic will not be written out to the persistent message store.

Durability and persistence are not the same things. A durable subscription tells the broker to preserve the subscription state in case the subscriber disconnects - any messages sent while the consumer is disconnected will be kept around. A non-durable subscription on the other hand is finite; if a subscriber disconnects, it missed any messages sent in the interim. All messages are stored in memory, and will not survive a broker restart.

Message persistence on the other hand stores messages for eventual delivery. This guards against catastrophic failure, or for later delivery to consumers who might not yet be active.

If you want to broadcast messages using pub-sub, and have the subscriptions appear durable and survive broker restarts you should use [virtual destinations](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html) instead of durable subscriptions.

No messages, persistent or non-persistent, will survive switching the broker off and deleting the data directory.